# In general, when is a $|\wp(S\times T)|$ equal to $|\wp S| \times |\wp T|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

let $S$ represent a set of $n$ elements, and let $T$ represent a set of $m$ elements, i.e. $|S| = n$, and $|T| = m$.

> When is: $$|\wp(S\times T)|=|\wp S| \times |\wp T|$$ true?

Comment: What is $S*T$ and what is $P(S)$ here?

Comment: S*T is the cartesian product of sets S & T; P(S) & P(T) are the subsets of the sets S & T.

Comment: When is $2^{n\cdot m} = 2^n\cdot 2^m$? *Almost* never...

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

If $A$ is a finite set then $|\wp(A)|=2^{|A|}$.

If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets then $|A\times B|=|A|\times|B|$.